# Remove xmlns attribute in xml so as to get simple plain xml node

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, linq-to-xml

I am using the following code

```
    var xmlFile = fromConfiguration + @"xyz.xml";
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);


    var xElement = document.Root;

    xElement.Add(new XElement("elementName", "elementText"));
    document.Save(xmlFile);
    XDocument documentN = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
    XElement element = (from xml2 in documentN.Descendants("elementName")
                        select xml2).FirstOrDefault();

    element.RemoveAttributes();
    documentN.Save(xmlFile);
```

This gives me..

```
 <elementName xmlns="">elementText</elementName>
```

xmlns is added by default.
Is there any way I can add without xmlns?

```
<elementName>elementText</elementName>
```

This is what I need to parse in my xsl file.

ANy help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is better to learn how to find or select elements in a namespace and how to construct them thus if you do

```
xElement.Add(new XElement(xElement.Name.Namespace + "elementName", "elementText"));
```

you don't have the problem of `xmlns="''`.

Comment: On a side  note I am using following xsl 

    <xsl:value-of select="/n1:root/n1:elementName"/>
I have checked it works only if xmlns is not present.

ANything that I am missing here?

Comment: Thanks It worked :)
wish I could kiss you. I have been banging my head for past 2 days.

I was missing xElement.Name.Namespace

Comment: Bear in mind that this isn't foolproof - see my answer for an example where it would fail.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ancestor elements must be setting a default namespace, e.g.

```
<foo xmlns="http://foo.bar">
  <!-- Your element name -->
</foo>
```

If you want:

```
<foo xmlns="http://foo.bar">
  <elementName>elementText</elementName>
</foo>
```

... then that means `elementName` is implicitly in a namespace of `http://foo.bar`, because the default is inherited. So you should use:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://foo.bar";
xElement.Add(new XElement(ns + "elementName", "elementText"));
```

If you might have different namespaces in different files, you could determine the default namespace programmatically - although it *may* not be the namespace of the root element, e.g.

```
<other:foo xmlns="http://foo.bar" xmlns:other="http://surprise">
  <!-- This is still in http://foo.bar -->
  <elementName>elementText</elementName>
</foo>
```

Comment: ANd something related to this would be
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
    var xElement = XDocument.Root;

This gives root node.
How about finding a specific node passing the element name as parameter.?

Comment: @Swaraj: That's an entirely different question. Read a LINQ to XML tutorials, and if you still haven't found an answer, post a new question.